# Issue with simple script mouse click script (Autokey)

Tags: coordinates, multiple-monitors, autokey

I am using a gis software that has 2 windows, I have  window A opened in my primary monitor and window B opened in the secondary monitor.

I am trying to make a script that will move the mouse to the secondary monitor and left click a certain position.

I tried to do it this way:

+z::
Click, 630 74 1

Problem is that when I am using the mouse in the window A, then when I use the script it will move to a position of the primary monitor.

Would it be possible to fix this by using the window title (which is different) in order to make the script go to window B before clicking?

Thank you